# XPATH _ Extract values XML

Tags: html, xml, power-automate

How Can I extract the characteristics values for the following XML code using XPATH?

Example: Extract displayName, firsName, lastName, etc.

This is my XML data:

```
<directory>
    <fieldset>
        <field id="displayName">Display name</field>
        <field id="firstName">First name</field>
        <field id="lastName">Last name</field>
        <field id="preferredName">Preferred name</field>
        <field id="jobTitle">Job title</field>
        <field id="workPhone">Work Phone</field>
        <field id="canUploadPhoto">Can Upload Photo</field>
    </fieldset>
    <employees>
        <employee id="229">
            <field id="displayName">Susan</field>
            <field id="firstName">TestName</field>
            <field id="canUploadPhoto">no</field>
        </employee>
 </employees>
</directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get actual values along the following XPath expression:

```
/directory/employees/employee/field[@id="displayName"]/text()
```